# Simple_html_Dom поиск элемента

Tags: simple-html-dom, php

Добрый день всем пару дней назад мне подсказали эту библиотеку,очень понравилось,действительно очень просто пользоваться ей и находить элементы.Но вот в данной ситуации не знаю как добраться до элемента,может проще его регуляркой спарсить? Подскажите пожалуйста

```
http://devilscity.combats.com/inf.pl?1272404620
```

Из этой ссылки надо добраться до элемента "Духовность" и спарсить его значение!

Comment: Народ подскажите пожалуйста кто знает

Comment: в данном случае, похоже, действительно придется использовать substr() и регулярные выражения, т.к. в HTML коде есть ошибки, и ни SimpleHTMLDom, ни SimpleXMLDocument, ни классы DOM* не могут добраться до нужной таблицы

Comment: Спасибо большое,а то  я ломаю тут голову,и никак не могу понять за что зацепиться,тут куча таблиц вложенный,+то что я ищу не обрамлено ни в один тэг.